# resque-retry - 'Retry attempt' is displayed as 'n/a'

Tags: ruby, resque-retry

I am using resque-retry to retry my job. I see the job that needs to be retried on the 'retry' tab of the resque-web interface. However, the '**Retry Attempts**' info is always '**n/a**'. Is there a reason for this?
Thanks in advance!